# setInterval in a clock doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clock

I have built a simple clock that counts from the date in the past to the current. But the set interval does not want to run and update.

I have tried

```
setInterval(updater, 100);
```

and

```
setInterval(updater(), 100);
```

and

```
setInterval(function() {
    let difference = calcTime();
    updateUI(difference);
}, 100);
```

If you would like to see the entire code. It's here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jgfeazdw/

```js
let curr, cov, diff, year, month, date, hours, mins, secs, msecs, finalSend;

// SAVING CURRENT TIME
const currTime = {
  cyr: new Date().getFullYear(),
  cmnth: new Date().getMonth(),
  cdate: new Date().getDate(),
  chrs: new Date().getHours(),
  cmins: new Date().getMinutes(),
  csecs: new Date().getSeconds(),
  cmsecs: new Date().getMilliseconds()
}

// SAVING TIME FROM PAST
const coverTime = {
  cyr: 2019,
  cmnth: 4,
  cdate: 11,
  chrs: 00,
  cmins: 00,
  csecs: 00,
  cmsecs: 00
}

// CALCULATE TIME FUNCTION
function calcTime() {
  curr = new Date(currTime.cyr, currTime.cmnth, currTime.cdate, currTime.chrs, currTime.cmins, currTime.csecs, currTime.cmsecs);

  cov = new Date(coverTime.cyr, coverTime.cmnth, coverTime.cdate, coverTime.chrs, coverTime.cmins, coverTime.csecs, coverTime.cmsecs);

  diff = new Date(curr - cov);

  year = (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)).toFixed();
  month = diff.getMonth();
  date = diff.getDate();
  hours = diff.getHours();
  mins = diff.getMinutes();
  secs = diff.getHours();
  msecs = diff.getMilliseconds();

  finalSend = {
    year: year,
    month: month,
    date: date,
    mins: mins,
    hours: hours,
    secs: secs,
    msecs: msecs
  }

  return finalSend;

}


// UPDATE UI FUNCTION
function updateUI(data) {

  // ADDS ZERO TO SINGLE DIGITS BEFORE ADDING TO UI
  function addZero(x) {
    if (x < 10) {
      x = '' + 0 + x;
      return x;
    } else {
      return x;
    }
  }

  // ADD UPDATED TIMES TO THE UI
  document.querySelector('.years').textContent = addZero(data.year);
  document.querySelector('.months').textContent = addZero(data.month);
  document.querySelector('.days').textContent = addZero(data.date);
  document.querySelector('.hours').textContent = addZero(data.hours);
  document.querySelector('.minutes').textContent = addZero(data.mins);
  document.querySelector('.seconds').textContent = addZero(data.secs);
  document.querySelector('.msecs').textContent = addZero(data.msecs);

}


function updater() {
  let difference = calcTime();
  updateUI(difference);
}


setInterval(updater, 100);
```

```css
/*///////// BODY*/

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#292929, black);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Krona One';
  size: 16px;
}


/*///////// WRAPPER */

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}


/*///////// MAINS */

.main {
  width: 75vw;
  height: 40vh;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25vh;
}


/*///////// SUBS */

.textBox {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.sub {
  font-size: .5rem;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.time {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.timerBox {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 1vw 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(70px, 10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="timerBox">
      <div class="sub">
        YEARS
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub">
        MONTHS
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub">
        DAYS
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub">
        HOURS
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub">
        MINUTES
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub">
        SECONDS
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub time">
        MILLISECS.
      </div>

      <div class="years time">
        12
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="months time">
        48
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="days time">
        79
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="hours time">
        43
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="minutes time">
        80
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="seconds time">
        75
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="msecs time">
        100
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"If you would like to see the entire code"_ - No. We want to see a [mcve] **in the question itself** (preferable as executable snippet (`<>`))

Comment: @Andreas I would, but I actually do not understand where the problem is to make it minimal!

Comment: `currTime` must be picked inside `calcTime` function, Kindly check

Comment: You're always calculating the difference between `currTime` and `coverTime`. Those times never change, they're only set once.

Comment: if you put console.log inside the `setInterval` you notice that it's executing fine. However you need to pass the new updated time back in to calc so it starts counting down

Comment: Got it! Thank you thank you. I moved currTime object into calcTime so it generates new time everytime it is called. So obvious once you see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some typos in your code. Also you're not using the latest time. You don't need to create a new object with times. you can just use `new Date()` inside your diff.

```
// SAVING TIME FROM PAST
const coverTime = {
  cyr: 2019,
  cmnth: 4,
  cdate: 11,
  chrs: 00,
  cmins: 00,
  csecs: 00,
  cmsecs: 00
}

// CALCULATE TIME FUNCTION
function calcTime() {
  const cov = new Date(coverTime.cyr, coverTime.cmnth, coverTime.cdate, coverTime.chrs, coverTime.cmins, coverTime.csecs, coverTime.cmsecs);

  const diff = new Date(new Date() - cov);
  const year = (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)).toFixed();
  const month = diff.getMonth();
  const date = diff.getDate();
  const hours = diff.getHours();
  const mins = diff.getMinutes();
  const secs = diff.getSeconds();
  const msecs = diff.getMilliseconds();

  return {
    year,
    month,
    date,
    mins,
    hours,
    secs,
    msecs
  }

}

// CACHE ELEMENTS
const yearEl = document.querySelector('.years')
const months = document.querySelector('.months')
const daysEl = document.querySelector('.days')
const hoursEl = document.querySelector('.hours')
const minutesEl = document.querySelector('.minutes')
const secondsEl = document.querySelector('.seconds')
const msecsEl = document.querySelector('.msecs');

// UPDATE UI FUNCTION
function updateUI(data) {

  // ADDS ZERO TO SINGLE DIGITS BEFORE ADDING TO UI
  function addZero(x) {
    if (x < 10) {
      x = '' + 0 + x;
      return x;
    } else {
      return x;
    }
  }

  // ADD UPDATED TIMES TO THE UI
  yearEl.textContent = addZero(data.year);
  msecsEl.textContent = addZero(data.month);
  daysEl.textContent = addZero(data.date);
  hoursEl.textContent = addZero(data.hours);
  minutesEl.textContent = addZero(data.mins);
  secondsEl.textContent = addZero(data.secs);
  msecsEl.textContent = addZero(data.msecs);
}


function updater() {
  let difference = calcTime();
  updateUI(difference);
}


setInterval(updater, 100);
```

Working example

https://jsfiddle.net/veoz0dng/13/

Comment: Thank you for this. It works and I found the silly typo and great tip about new Date(). Just curious why you used 'innerHTML' instead of 'textContent'?

Comment: you can stick with textContent. I was just checking if you had querySelector properly set. I've made some improvements by moving `querySelectors` out of `updateUI`  so it's cached. Also removing global `let` and return because it's ES6 you don't have to explicitly declare...

Answer (score 1):

Your currentTime didn't update at all, all you need to do is to move your current time block into the calcTime() function.

```
    let currTime = {
    cyr: new Date().getFullYear(),
    cmnth: new Date().getMonth(),
    cdate: new Date().getDate(),
    chrs: new Date().getHours(),
    cmins: new Date().getMinutes(),
    csecs: new Date().getSeconds(),
    cmsecs: new Date().getMilliseconds()
  }
```

And typo here:

```
secs = diff.getHours();
```

Result :

```js
let curr, cov, diff, year, month, date, hours, mins, secs, msecs, finalSend;


// SAVING TIME FROM PAST
const coverTime = {
  cyr: 2019,
  cmnth: 4,
  cdate: 11,
  chrs: 00,
  cmins: 00,
  csecs: 00,
  cmsecs: 00
}

// CALCULATE TIME FUNCTION
function calcTime() {
  let currTime = {
    cyr: new Date().getFullYear(),
    cmnth: new Date().getMonth(),
    cdate: new Date().getDate(),
    chrs: new Date().getHours(),
    cmins: new Date().getMinutes(),
    csecs: new Date().getSeconds(),
    cmsecs: new Date().getMilliseconds()
  }
  curr = new Date(currTime.cyr, currTime.cmnth, currTime.cdate, currTime.chrs, currTime.cmins, currTime.csecs, currTime.cmsecs);

  cov = new Date(coverTime.cyr, coverTime.cmnth, coverTime.cdate, coverTime.chrs, coverTime.cmins, coverTime.csecs, coverTime.cmsecs);

  diff = new Date(curr - cov);

  year = (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)).toFixed();
  month = diff.getMonth();
  date = diff.getDate();
  hours = diff.getHours();
  mins = diff.getMinutes();
  secs = diff.getSeconds();
  msecs = diff.getMilliseconds();

  finalSend = {
    year,
    month,
    date,
    mins,
    hours,
    secs,
    msecs
  }

  return finalSend;

}

// ADDS ZERO TO SINGLE DIGITS BEFORE ADDING TO UI
function addZero(x) {
  if (x < 10) {
    x = '' + 0 + x;
    return x;
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}


// UPDATE UI FUNCTION
function updateUI(data) {



  // ADD UPDATED TIMES TO THE UI
  document.querySelector('.years').textContent = addZero(data.year);
  document.querySelector('.months').textContent = addZero(data.month);
  document.querySelector('.days').textContent = addZero(data.date);
  document.querySelector('.hours').textContent = addZero(data.hours);
  document.querySelector('.minutes').textContent = addZero(data.mins);
  document.querySelector('.seconds').textContent = addZero(data.secs);
  document.querySelector('.msecs').textContent = addZero(data.msecs);
}


function updater() {
  updateUI(calcTime());
}


setInterval(updater, 100);
```

```css
/*///////// BODY*/

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#292929, black);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Krona One';
  size: 16px;
}


/*///////// WRAPPER */

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}


/*///////// MAINS */

.main {
  width: 75vw;
  height: 40vh;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25vh;
}


/*///////// SUBS */

.textBox {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.sub {
  font-size: .5rem;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.time {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.timerBox {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 1vw 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(50px, 10%) minmax(20px, 5%) minmax(70px, 10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="timerBox">
      <div class="sub">
        YEARS
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub">
        MONTHS
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub">
        DAYS
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub">
        HOURS
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub">
        MINUTES
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub">
        SECONDS
      </div>
      <div class="colon sub"></div>
      <div class="sub time">
        MILLISECS.
      </div>

      <div class="years time">
        12
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="months time">
        48
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="days time">
        79
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="hours time">
        43
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="minutes time">
        80
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="seconds time">
        75
      </div>
      <div class="colon time">:</div>
      <div class="msecs time">
        100
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you only asked for to make interval works, good luck on your simple clock ! it looks cool !